# About nodejs push data to browser open source framework

Tags: node.js, linux, curl

Now I want a nodejs open source or open source framework to push some data to users browser .

example when I use curl post or get like url "http://localhost:3303?pushdata=sth" to nodejs server ,nodejs server received the data `pushdata=sth` and push to users browser `sth`

I need some source code or source framework complete my project requirement,
thanks

Comment: maybe like php framework "http://www.workerman.net:2123/" but I need nodejs

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about somthing like http://socket.io/?  you would use an express route to create the rest api on the node server, then push a message out to the browsers connected to it.

Comment: I know socket.io ,but I need a framework or some source code